# Display K6 data as Locust does

Tags: k6

We're currently using [Locust](https://locust.io/) and we want to switch into [k6](https://k6.io) (and implement docker).

The docker implementation is working, k6 command works as expected.

I've found the [k6-reporter](https://github.com/benc-uk/k6-reporter) repository to render the result as an HTML.

[image]

But I'd like to render an HTML document similar to Locust (grouped by path and and maybe adding graph too in a second time).

[image]

I'm struggling a little to understand how to render custom metrics, so I'm asking for you help.

```
import http from "k6/http";
import { htmlReport } from "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/benc-uk/k6-reporter/main/dist/bundle.js";
import { check, group } from 'k6';
import { Trend, Counter,  } from 'k6/metrics';

const iteration = 2
const exposedPort = 32980;
const uri = 'localhost'
const urlHttp = 'http://'+ uri +':'+ exposedPort +'/'

let homeScenario = {
  executor: "shared-iterations",
  vus: 1,
  iterations: iteration,
  startTime: "0s",
  exec: 'homePageExec',
  gracefulStop: '5s',
}

let scenarios = {
  homeScenario: homeScenario,
}

const trend_home = new Trend('/');
const counter_home = new Counter('my_counter');
export function homePageExec() {
  group('home "/" ', function() {
    const tags = {
      hometag: 'hometag'
    }
    const res = http.get(urlHttp, {
      tags: tags
    });
    trend_home.add(1, tags)
    check(res, {'is status 200': (r) => r.status === 200,}, tags);
    counter_home.add(1, tags);
  })
}


export const options = {
  insecureSkipTLSVerify: true,
  scenarios: scenarios,
};

export default function () { //can this be empty ?
}

export function handleSummary(data) {
  return {
    "perf/perf.html": htmlReport(data),
  };
}
```

Comment: Which part are you struggling with? Have you read the docs? It comes with examples and the schema: https://k6.io/docs/results-output/end-of-test/custom-summary/

Comment: Struggling with render details by URL (like locust), I read the docs but I don't understand how to do it